# I'm getting this error in eclipse while using selenium Jar files:

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

Following is my simple `Java` code for `selenium`:

```
package myPackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class MyClass {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

     System.out.println("My First Selenoium Class");

     WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
     String baseURL = "http://newtours.demoaut.com";
     String expectedTitle = "Welcome: Mercury Tours";
     String actualTitle = "";

     driver.get(baseURL);
     actualTitle = driver.getTitle();


     if(actualTitle.contentEquals(expectedTitle)){
        System.out.println("Titles are same");
     }
     else {
        System.out.println("Different Titles");
     }

     driver.close();
     System.exit(0);
   }

}
```

There are 2 errors occuring at the `if` condition:

> Error1 : The method contentEquals(StringBuffer) in the type String is not   applicable for the arguments (String).
>   Error2 : The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Please help me resolving this.

Comment: It sounds to me that you classpath is not set correctly

Comment: clean project, then build again, also check `Build Path` from `prefrence` in eclipse

Answer (score 1):

contentEquals wants a StringBuffer argument:

```
StringBuffer expectedTitle = "Welcome: Mercury Tours";
```

Comment: thank you for replying, but i tried this too. I get an error again on this particular line asking to change the data type from StringBuffer to String, and the cycle goes on.